# Transmitting parameters from script to script, how?

Tags: parameters, unity-game-engine, unityscript, transmission

I know there are a few answers on that question, but they don't work for me or I am only to stupid. Sorry.

Here are my scripts:

menu_options.js - http://pastebin.com/NFXD3ZgP

Transmitter.js - http://pastebin.com/kCmGTgbH

i've attached the Transmitter.js to a specific object. It's called "_Transmitter".

If I run my scripts I get following Error:

```
Assets/Script/menu_options.js(7,40): BCE0023: No appropriate version of 'UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent' for the argument list '(UnityEngine.GameObject)' was found.
```

Why? And what does it mean?

What did I understand wrong in the tutorials and answers?

I also tried this:

```
trans = Transmitter.gameObject.GetComponent(Transmitter);
```

and this:

```
trans = Transmitter.GetComponent(Transmitter);
```

Comment: I Get it! PlayerPrefs.SetInt("light", 50); and PlayerPrefs.GetInt("light"); i am using now!

Comment: `PlayerPrefs` is overkill when all you want to do is pass a parameter between scripts. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("variablenname", 1);
```

and

```
var v1 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("variablenname");
```

works great!

Comment: Please make sure to keep your posts in English. The site is English only and looking at your questions you speak it just fine. ;)

Answer (score 1):

To pass a parameter to another script you must first have a reference to that script.

ScriptA

```
function Start()
{
    var reference : GameObject = GameObject.Find("Name Of GameObject").GetComponent("ScriptB");

    reference.setValue(50);
}
```

So we `Find()` the GameObject that has the script, we first need the name of the GameObject that has it. Then we use `GetComponent()` to grab the script's reference. Then we make the function call to set a parameter.

---

ScriptB

```
private var myValue : int;

function setValue(var amount : int)
{
    myValue = amount;
}
```

Comment: Oh, OK thanks but i don't need to call funktions. But THANKS!